# Как получить данные которые я передал через Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

С помощью react-router-dom я хочу передать некоторые параметры используя хуки.

```
<Link key={index} to={{
      pathname: quiz,
      state: {
        test: "test"
      }
     }}>
        <span>Test</span>
</Link>
```

Компонент в который я хочу передать параметры

```
import React from "react";
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";

export default function Child() {
    let {name} = useParams();
  return (
    <div className="user">
        <h1>{name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Как мне достать параметры которые я передал?
Я пробовал через location.state но так не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так у react-router-dom имеется хук useLocation.

В компоненте Child вызови его:

```
const { state } = useLocation();
```

И в твоем state должно быть поле test. При условии, что компонент Child рендерится по тому pathname, который указан в Link